# Angular2 assign object value from method parameter object

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on Angular 5 application. I have model class RoleClaimEntryDataModel and in one injectable service I have method 'UpdateRoleClaimById' receiving RoleClaimEntryDataModel as parameter and I am trying to assign this object to RoleClaimEntryDataModel of class but I get error

### error

```
Type 'RoleClainEntryDataModel' is not assignable to type 'typeof RoleClaimEntryDataModel'/
Property 'prototype' is missing in type 'RoleClaimEntryDataModel'
```

### Model class

```
export class RoleClaimEntryDataModel{
  roleId:string;
  claimId:string;
  isClaimAssignToRole:boolean;
}
```

### Injectable Service A

```
 @Injectable()
 export class UpdateRoleClaimCommand extends BaseCommand<boolean> {

  public data = RoleClaimEntryDataModel;

  initialise(): void {
      super.setBody(this.data);
  }
}
```

### Injectable Service B

```
@Injectable()
export class PermissionDataService{

constructor(
    private updateRoleClaimCommand: UpdateRoleClaimCommand
){}

 public UpdateRoleClaimById(roleClaimEntryDataModel: RoleClaimEntryDataModel)
{
    this.updateRoleClaimCommand.data = roleClaimEntryDataModel; // throw error here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `data` property in your `UpdateRoleClaimCommand` refers to the type `RoleClaimEntryDataModel`, not a variable of type `RoleClaimEntryDataModel`

This is how it should be

```
@Injectable()
 export class UpdateRoleClaimCommand extends BaseCommand<boolean> {

  public data: RoleClaimEntryDataModel;

  initialise(): void {
      super.setBody(this.data);
  }
}
```